# Basic jQuery .load Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery's .load function to dynamically load content into my webpage. This seem so simple, but I cannot make it work. To try and figure it out, I made a test page with just basic structure, but the external content still won't load:

jquery.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Test</title>
<script src="jquery1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    $('#foo').load('test.html');
</script>

<div id="foo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

test.html

```
<p>Text text</p>
```

I'm sure I have made a tiny error, but I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: You need to wrap your loading into a `ready()` block.

Comment: Or, since you have your `<script>` in the body, put it *at the end of body*.

Comment: To elaborate on @Pekka's comment, replace your JS with this: `$(document).ready(function(){$('#foo').load('test.html');});` or, more simply, `$(function(){$('#foo').load('test.html');});`

Comment: You might also check to make sure that jquery1.5.min.js and test.html exist in the same folder as the snippet you have provided above. Also, please be sure to mark the correct answer as Accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: They all reside in the same folder, I have moved the <script> to the end, and it still does not load. I feel dumb to continue asking this, but why won't it work?!

Comment: Are you testing this on your local computer using a file:/// address? If so, that's the problem. You need to serve the files from an HTTP server.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem. Thank you very much for that--time to set up a local web server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your script in the `$(document).ready()` otherwise `#foo` won't exist when the script is executed:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#foo').load('test.html');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Or, if you like shortcuts - $(function(){/* code here runs on ready */});

Comment: If the script appeared anywhere after `#foo` it will work without the `.ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the document to be ready before you can access the DOM.  Just add a $(document).ready() around your original code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Test</title>
<script src="jquery1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#foo').load('test.html');
    });
</script>

<div id="foo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you want a shorter code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').load('test.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Informally, what's happening is that, as your browser reads the code you wrote, it's drawing its contents as it goes along. When it reaches your `<script>` tag, it executes it. But when `$("#foo")` gets executed, the browser's still processing the `<script>` and hasn't reached the part of the code where you told it there's a div called foo, so the browser doesn't know it exists, and jquery will just find nothing.

Of course, the idea that the browser will just sequentially read your code and render it as it goes is naive at best, so while it might seem that just moving the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the code would work, you're not actually *guaranteed* it will work. Instead, the browser will notify you when it's done drawing the page by firing a load (and possibly a DOMContentLoaded) event. So all code that depends on the whole html being drawn should be executed in an event handler bound to those events.

jQuery makes waiting for the page to be loaded easy, just use something like this:

```
$.ready(function() {
  doStuff();
});
```